# Combine lists R RisMed different length

Tags: r, list

I gathered different lists from the RISMed package and would like to know how to combine to lists of different lengths and then transform them into a data frame.

List #1 with Authors' names:

```
[[1]] - First element of the list
  LastName  ForeName Initials order
1    Ellis   Peter M       PM     1
2    Verma     Sunil        S     2
3   Sehdev   Sandeep        S     3
4   Younus    Jawaid        J     4
5   Leighl Natasha B       NB     5
```

List #2 with PubMed IDs

```
[[1]] - First element of the list
27998745
```

I managed to compile all the authors into one dataset through the ldply function of the plyr package. However, I would like to merge it with the PubMed IDs. Exemple below:

```
  LastName  ForeName Initials order   PubMedID
1    Ellis   Peter M       PM     1   27998745
2    Verma     Sunil        S     2   27998745
3   Sehdev   Sandeep        S     3   27998745
4   Younus    Jawaid        J     4   27998745
5   Leighl Natasha B       NB     5   27998745
```

That being done for all the ~5000 IDs I have.

Thanks a lot,

Romain

EDIT: 
This works fine but for one article at a time.
Result<- cbind(List1[[2]],PubMedID= List2[[2]])

The mapply function does not work as it puts different lists (e.g. forenames) into different variables. The PubMedID got into a row but not listed.

Comment: Your list #2 contains _only_ the PubMed IDs?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is kind of a join between two tables "by" the list indice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to `cbind` the two parts together.

```
mapply(cbind, list1, PubMedID=list2)
```

This successively cbinds the corresponding elements of the two lists, producing a list of data frames. If you then want to put them into one big data frame:

```
rbind.fill(mapply(cbind, list1, PubMedID=list2))
```

Comment: mapply(cbind, list1, PubMedID=list2) produces a matrix of lists 5 x 3 (if I use three articles).